# How to convert android app traffic to proxy and decrypt TLS traffic?

Tags: android, ssl, https, proxy

**Advance declaration**

There are some questions about android app traffic

[How to capture app traffic on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757316/how-to-capture-app-traffic-on-android)

But them aims are `capture` not `capture and decrypt`

---

I want to decrypt Android app(called seat) TLS traffic

I have Windows 10 Pro, Android 8.0(rooted with full iptables supported)

seat use TLS connections with `202.194.76.30:8443`, I don't know which application layer protocol it used.

Maybe it uses HTTP (I used httpie cli to test API, `http --verify no https://seat.ujn.edu.cn:8443/auth/signIn`, response is `http`)

But i'm very sure it uses TLS

My solution is:

1. force seat uses http proxy, I use ProxyDroid to do this, it convert any tcp connections to http proxy(http CONNECT)
2. ProxtDroid redirects app traffic to my PC(192.168.137.1) where mitmproxy listen on 9090
3. mitmproxy dump out all TLS `master key` to `mitsslog.log` using `MITMPROXY_SSLKEYLOGFILE` env variable
4. I use wireshark to decrypt TLS, read TLS master key from `mitsslog.log`

But problem is seat don't use proxy

I use tcpdump on android to capture all traffic to 202.194.76.30, as you can see, seat app don't use my proxy!
[image]

I can capture android app traffic, but cannot decrypt it.

[image]

Here are android nat tables

[image]

My ProxyDroid configuration

[image]

I have searched three days, I have read all docs on mitmproxy.

None of them works. The only way left is ask for stackoverflow-ers helps.

mitmproxy tell me you can use transparent, but Windows 10 don't support netsh routing function. so I cannot use NAT

I tried use virtualbox, but I'm using hyper-v because of Docker for Windows. I cannot use another virtual technology

I come here to ask for your help. I will try give you more detail if you could help me

:)

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself

Add following rule solve my question.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j REDIRECT --to 8124
```

We need redirect conn to ProxyDroid listen port

let it to convert tcp conn to http proxy.

used my whole day to solve it!!